# D3.js getting nodes to appear in middle without "bounce"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have a D3 setup using "Nodes" and "Lines". When the graph first appears, it bounces in with gravity until it settles in the middle. Does anyone know of a way to have it appear automatically in the middle without the "bounce" sort of effect?

P.S I am using force layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling start resets the cooling parameter, alpha; alpha decays exponentially as the layout converges on its solution, and then stops so as to avoid wasting the cpu. There's no jittering on start (other than coincident nodes, which is necessary to avoid a divide by zero). However, anytime you have conflicting forces and geometric constraints (links), it's natural to expect the layout to adjust when starting.

If you want to avoid this bounce, you either need to keep the graph permanently hot (say by calling `d3.timer(function() { force.resume(); })`) or you'd need to do something else, like adjust the alpha parameter manually to reheat gradually instead of instantaneously.

Edit: In 2.8.x, you can avoid the first bounce entirely by running the force layout synchronously on startup. For example: http://bl.ocks.org/1667139

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Another strategy I've used before is to gradually increase the radii of each node from zero over the first, say, 50 or 100 force ticks. You can see what that looks like (in Protovis, but it would behave the same way in d3) in the Dorling cartograms on the [one.org data site](http://one.org/data/en/data/oda-global-gni/).